# RuneCountInString get invalid count when character contain 「U+FE0F」

Tags: go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhDW.png)

```
t := "️"
fmt.Println(utf8.RuneCountInString(t))
```

i think print count == 1 is better. why it return 2

Comment: RuneCount != GraphemeCount != PhonemeCount != ByteCount.

Answer (score 2):

The character `️` is represented by 2 code points (**U+1F236** and **U+FE0F**). “Code point” is a bit of a mouthful, so Go introduces a shorter term for the concept: rune. `utf8.RuneCountInString` returns the number of runes `2` and works as expected.

Try the package `github.com/rivo/uniseg` if you want to count the number of characters.

The demo below should explain it better:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"

    "github.com/rivo/uniseg"
)

func main() {
    s1 := "️"                           // UTF-8 input text
    s2 := "\U0001f236\ufe0f"             // <== the explicit Unicode code points
    s3 := "\xf0\x9f\x88\xb6\xef\xb8\x8f" // the explicit UTF-8 bytes
    fmt.Println("s1:", s1)
    fmt.Println("s1 == s2:", s1 == s2)
    fmt.Println("s2 == s3:", s2 == s3)
    fmt.Println("len(s1):", len(s1), "bytes")
    fmt.Println("runes:")
    for pos, r := range s1 {
        fmt.Printf("  %d: %X\n", pos, r)
    }
    fmt.Println("utf8.RuneCount:", utf8.RuneCount([]byte(s1)))
    fmt.Println("utf8.RuneCountInString:", utf8.RuneCountInString(s1))

    // GraphemeClusterCount returns the number of user-perceived characters
    // (grapheme clusters) for the given string.
    fmt.Println("uniseg.GraphemeClusterCount:", uniseg.GraphemeClusterCount(s1))
}
```

Output:

```
s1: ️
s1 == s2: true
s2 == s3: true
len(s1): 7 bytes
runes:
  0: 1F236
  4: FE0F
utf8.RuneCount: 2
utf8.RuneCountInString: 2
uniseg.GraphemeClusterCount: 1
```

References:

- Rob Pike's excellent article [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings#code-points-characters-and-runes).
- The "String literals" section in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals).
- Henrique Vicente's blog post: [UTF-8 strings with Go: len(s) isn't enough](https://henvic.dev/posts/go-utf8/).

Comment: The second rune is a variation selector, which specifies a glyph variant for a preceding character, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block). For emojis U+FE0E and U+FE0F could be applied. 
It could be also rendered without variation selector, e.g. do sth like `emoji := "\U0001f236"` followed by `fmt.Printf("%s: %d runes: %x\n", emoji, utf8.RuneCountInString(emoji), []rune(emoji))` and it will output `: 1 runes: [1f236]`

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/strings states that `In general, a character may be represented by a number of different sequences of code points, and therefore different sequences of UTF-8 bytes.`

Comment: Yep, sure. My comment referred solely to the specifics of the case mentioned.